# glfwInit needs to be called twice for shared libraries, why would that be?

Tags: c++, glfw, dynamic-linking

Experimenting around I found something interesting let's say we have A.cpp and B.cpp A.cpp in pseudocode is something like this:

```
// Load library
void (*InitializeRendering)(GLFWwindow*);
    InitializeRendering = (decltype(InitializeRendering)) dlsym(renderer_handle, INIT_RENDERING_FUNC);
    
 glfwInit();
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
 auto window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

InitializeRendering(window);
```

And then B.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
void InitializeRendering(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwInit();
    
    // Init vulkan surface from window
}
```

This setup works, what's interesting is, if you delete the call to glfwInit() inside B.cpp things won't work anymore, you very much need to have it initialized in the shared library object. I am wondering why this would be the case? It seems that the global state between the 2 binaries is not shared.

Comment: Is GLFW linked as a static or dynamic library?

Comment: Dynamic it is loaded through dlopen.

Comment: Is the base address of the GLFW library the same for both the executable and the dynamic library?

Comment: "It seems that the global state between the 2 binaries is not shared". This is exactly the case for shared libraries loaded with `dlopen` without `RTLD_GLOBAL`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That should probably be an answer.

Comment: @OP Does is work if you link both component (_A_ main executable and _B_ shared object) with libglfw.so instead of dlopening?

Comment: As in static linking? In that case it does work.

Comment: As in using `-lglfw` linkage time (both main executable and plugin). What is the resason not to do so?

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy I mean I do do that, but that won;t initialize the global scope on its own, which is what glfwInit() does.

Comment: Oh I jus tnoticed I miss answered on question glfw is statically linked